# Docker compose with systemd

Tags: docker, docker-compose, systemd

I would like to use this docker image https://github.com/eniocarboni/docker-rockylinux-systemd and build upon it to use in a docker-compose with multiple containers.

Can anyone explain how to include the following:
`volume=/sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:rw`

in the docker-compose file?

I have tried this but it doesnt work:

```
volumes:
  - /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:rw
```

And gives the following error:  `Couldn't find an alternative telinit implementation to spawn.`

Which according to the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36545105/docker-couldnt-find-an-alternative-telinit-implementation-to-spawn) seems to be down to the volume.

I can run the rocky linux image with the instructions:

```
docker run --detach --privileged --volume=/sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:rw --cgroupns=host eniocarboni/docker-rockylinux-systemd:latest
```

fine - just cant get it to work with compose and an entry-point.

Comment: were you able to solv it at the end or you still need help ?

Comment: Yeah - I got it working, though would have to check how as it was a while ago.